# Errors while using `appendCypher()` in RNeo4j

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I am trying to create a graph database in R using the `RNeo4j` package. Basically what @Nicloe White has shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh_79goBRUk) is what I am trying to achieve entirely through the RStudio IDE. I have read in the [data](https://data.consumerfinance.gov/views/s6ew-h6mp/rows.csv) into R and done some basic housekeeping on the date fields by using the `lubridate` package. Thereafter I am following what Nicole has shown [here](https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j) for the `hflights` dataset. This is the relevant code:

```
query="
CREATE (complaint:Complaint {id: TOINT({ComplaintID})})
SET complaint.day = ({ComplaintDay}),
    complaint.month = ({ComplaintMonth}),
    complaint.year = ({ComplaintYear})
MERGE (company:Company {name:{CompanyName}})
MERGE (response:Response {name:{Companyresponsetoconsumer}})

CREATE (complaint) -[:AGAINST]-> (company)
CREATE (response) -[r:TO]-> (complaint)

SET r.timely = CASE {Timelyresponse} WHEN 'Yes' THEN true ELSE false END,
    r.disputed = CASE {Consumerdisputed} WHEN 'Yes' THEN true ELSE false END


"

tx = newTransaction(graph)

for(i in 1:nrow(complaint)) {
  row = complaint[i, ]
  appendCypher(tx, query,
               ComplaintID=complaint$Complaint.ID,
               ComplaintDay=complaint$Complaint.Day,
               ComplaintMonth=complaint$Complaint.Month,
               ComplaintYear=complaint$Complaint.Year,
               CompanyName=complaint$Company,
               Companyresponsetoconsumer=complaint$Company.response.to.consumer,
               Timelyresponse=complaint$Timely.response.,
               Consumerdisputed=complaint$Consumer.disputed.)
}
commit(tx)

summary(graph)
```

However, when I run the `for` loop, I get the following error:

```
Error in appendCypher.transaction(tx, query, ComplaintID = 

complaint$Complaint.ID,  : 
  Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError
Expected a String or Number, got: List(1913026, 99413, 1420666, 1139505, 850511, 211452, 299293, 967118, 1342525, 218870, 936088, 1577433, 396460, 976892, 1713179, 985796, 1274906, 1524883, 549683, 375379, 2083877, 1804301, 568928, 643695, 2013448, 1822596, 1054868, 1058533, 1972148, 1053127, 1546919, 1974786, 1386150, 558306, 2029982, 1812827, 2112000, 1279031, 1729024, 811685, 423229, 211371, 550247, 1837165, 589977, 363963, 773706, 1422738, 362615, 1918434, 31932, 101419, 109634, 799711, 568707, 425802, 1354727, 905367, 433560, 950090, 1615178, 1085081, 1842311, 55218, 82206, 8990, 1716274, 1199075, 315208, 976080, 1747751, 1424814, 757803, 61250, 592018, 974917, 2046258, 1901776, 123518, 1362552, 257123, 1212622, 1663172, 1200587, 84365, 358901, 1920239, 691273, 226122, 36142, 1615314, 809300, 1987176, 596079, 1619346, 1261257, 984128, 793228, 173250, 249440, 192131, 1759419, 1394747, 1316550, 1890080, 862502, 1192961, 506058, 2000389,
```

The status code indicates that perhaps the `complaint$Complaint.ID` type is not supported. But wouldn't the `TOINT` take care of this?

Would appreciate some help here please.

Comment: you are passing list in ComplaintID , and it is expecting a String or Number

Comment: `str(complaint$Complaint.ID)` reveals that it's an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really stupid mistake in the `for` loop. This is what works:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(complaint)) {
  row = complaint[i, ]
  appendCypher(tx, query,
               ComplaintID=row$Complaint.ID,
               ComplaintDay=row$Complaint.Day,
               ComplaintMonth=row$Complaint.Month,
               ComplaintYear=row$Complaint.Year,
               CompanyName=row$Company,
               Companyresponsetoconsumer=row$Company.response.to.consumer,
               Timelyresponse=row$Timely.response.,
               Consumerdisputed=row$Consumer.disputed.)
}
```